# Phantom Vibration from com.android.providers.downloads

Tags: adb, vibration

I've found the source of roughly 10x phantom vibrations (e.g. vibrations without notification or clear cause) daily.

```
startTime: 9 Apr 2019, 15:20:33, effect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 100, 150, 100], mAmplitudes=[0, 255, 0, 255], mRepeat=-1}, originalEffect: Waveform{mTimings=[0, 100, 150, 100], mAmplitudes=[0, -1, 0, -1], mRepeat=-1}, usageHint: 5, uid: 10016, opPkg: com.android.providers.downloads, type: null
```

All originate from the package

```
com.android.providers.downloads
```

I am trying to determine what the root cause for this issue is.

Device Details:
*Huawei P30 Pro (VOG-L29) running 9.1.0.124*

Comment: Do you have a pending download or a downloaded item you have not opened?